# Integrality of $\frac{n}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^3}{6}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been asked to provide a proof for

> If $n$ is an integer then
>
> $$\frac{n}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^3}{6}$$
>
> is also an integer.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint:  You can express any $n$ as $6m+k$ for $k\in\{0,\dots,5\}$.  Try re-expressing $\frac n3+\frac{n^2}2+\frac{n^3}6$ in terms of $m$ and $i$. Then prove the statement for each of the 6 values of $i$.

Comment: One way is to factorize it, to see that it's $n(n+1)(n+2)/6$.

Answer (score 13):

Hint:$$\frac{n}{6}(n^2+3n+2)=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(n+2)$$
What can you say about the divisibility of $n,(n+1),(n+2)$ by $2$ and $3$?

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $\ \ \displaystyle \frac{n^3}{6} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{3}\, =\, \frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}6\,=\, \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}6\,  =\, {n+2\choose 3}\in\Bbb Z$

**Remark** $\ \ $ This is a special case of a classical result of Polya and Ostrowski $(1920).$ Namely, $\,f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ is an integer-valued polynomial, i.e.  $f(\mathbb Z)\subset \mathbb Z\:,\:$ iff $f(x)$ is an integral linear combination of binomial coefficients ${x\choose k},\:$ for $\: k\le \deg f$. For a proof see e.g. Polya And Szego, *Problems and theorems in analysis*, vol II, [Problem 85 p. 129](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCa2CmAt8pwC&pg=PA129) and its [solution on p. 320.](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCa2CmAt8pwC&pg=PA320)  This theorem has been extended to more general rings (e.g. Dedekind domains) by Cahen and others.

Answer (score 5):

Start with $n=1$ and you'll get $S(1)=\frac13+\frac12+\frac16=1$, so at least here we know that we get an integer back. Now calculate the difference 
$$
\Delta S(n)= S(n+1)-S(n) = \left(\frac{n+1}{3}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}+\frac{(n+1)^3}{6}\right)-\left(\frac{n}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n^3}{6}\right)\\
$$

> $$\hskip1.7in =\frac12n(n+3)+1.$$

This gives you the value you have to add to $S(n)$.
Can you see why $\Delta S(n)$ always gives an integer independant of $n$?

If you can, you know that, once you've started out with an integer you always add integers...

Comment: And if you can't immediately see why $\Delta S(n) = S(n+1) - S(n)$ always gives an integer, consider $\Delta \Delta S(n) = \Delta S(n+1) - \Delta S(n)$... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If you can collect all the terms together into a single fraction, the problem reduces to showing that the numerator will always be divisible by the denominator.

Hint 2: Do you know modular arithmetic? If not, see Tim's comment.