# Polynomial with integer values

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, integer-valued-polynomials

I'm looking for a polynomial $P \in \mathbb Q[x]$ with $P(\mathbb Z) \subset \mathbb Z$, with $P \notin \mathbb Z[x]$

I found that $f_n := \frac{1}{n}x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-(n-1))$ is such an element.

My question is : are these the "only" solutions ?

More precisely, if $I$ denote the ideal generated by the $f_n$, my question is :

**Is there a such polynomial $P$ with $P \notin I$ ??**

*edit : I forgot to precise the condition $P \notin \mathbb Z[x]$*

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/410148) answer could be interesting to you.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130041

Comment: @Watson : Thanks ! Wahou this question was long time ago ...

Comment: Yes :-) but apparently there are a lot of researches about "integer-valued polynomials" for more general rings. There is even [an entire book](http://www.ams.org/books/surv/048/surv048-endmatter.pdf) on that topic!

Comment: This book looks really cool, especially some link with algebraic geometry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomials with integer values are a *subring* of $\mathbf Q[x]$, and the polynomials $f_n$ are a `basis` for this ring as a $\mathbf Z$-module. The ideal $I$ is the ring itself, since $f_0=1$.

As a ring, though contained in the PID $\mathbf Q[x]$, it is non-noetherian. Actually, it is a `Prüfer domain` (non-noetherian generalization of a Dedekind domain) of Krull dimension $2$. Its finitely generated ideals are invertible and generated by at most $2$ elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want that $f \notin \mathbb{Z}[x]$, so I'm interested by the ideal generated by $(f_n)_{n>2}$. 
But if I understand your answer, there is no solutions ?

Comment: The only thing I'm sure of is that any polynomial with integer values is a linear combination with coefficients in $\mathbf Z$ of the $f_n$. According to the values of the coefficients it may or may not be in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Btw, you speak of an ideal $I$ in what ring? $\mathbf Q[x]$?

Comment: Ok perfect that was exactly my question, thanks. My ideal was in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.